# linked report from a chart- SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, charts, reporting

I am displaying a table in an SSRS report. What I want to do is, if I click on one of the columns in this chart, it opens another report by passing parameters from parent report to child report.

How can I achieve this?

Regards

Manjot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found-
Go to parent report, rightclick table.
Go to actions. Fix parameters and Jump to report...